# How to stub a libary function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, sinon

For example, if I have **main.js** calling **a** defined in **src/lib/a.js**, and function **a** calls **node-uuid.v1**, how can I stub **node-uuid.v1** when testing **main.js**?

**main.js**

```
const a = require("./src/lib/a").a

const main = () => {
  return a()
}

module.exports = main
```

**src/lib/a.js**

```
const generateUUID = require("node-uuid").v1

const a = () => {
  let temp = generateUUID()
  return temp
}

module.exports = {
  a
}
```

**tests/main-test.js**

```
const assert = require("assert")
const main = require("../main")
const sinon = require("sinon")
const uuid = require("node-uuid")

describe('main', () => {
  it('should return a newly generated uuid', () => {
    sinon.stub(uuid, "v1").returns("121321")

    assert.equal(main(), "121321")
  })
})
```

The `sinon.stub(...)` statement doesn't stub uuid.v1 for *src/lib/a.js* as the above test fails.

Is there a way to globally a library function so that it does the specified behavior whenever it gets called?

Comment: If you absolutely have to stub some code to write reasonable tests, I'd suggest you only stub your direct dependencies.  Anything else increases coupling too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure the stub before importing the main module. In this way the module will call the stub instead of the original function.

```
const assert = require("assert")
const sinon = require("sinon")
const uuid = require("node-uuid")

describe('main', () => {
  it('should return a newly generated uuid', () => {
    sinon.stub(uuid, "v1").returns("121321")
    const main = require("../main")

    assert.equal(main(), "121321")
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that node-uuid is deprecated as you can see by this warning

> [Deprecation warning: The use of require('uuid') is deprecated and
>   will not be supported after version 3.x of this module. Instead, use
>   require('uuid/[v1|v3|v4|v5]') as shown in the examples below.]

About how to stub that for testing would be a bit more harder than before as actually there is no an easy way to mock a standalone function using sinon

Creating a custom module

```
//custom uuid
module.exports.v1 = require('uuid/v1');
```

Requiring uuid from the custom module in your project

```
const uuid = require('<path_to_custom_module>');

Sinon.stub(uuid, 'v1').returns('12345');
```